# Optical Character Recognition Android with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, ocr

I'm currently working on a project which involves optical character recognition in Android and really need some pointers from somebody who has some experience in the area.

I was told to start off by setting up OpenCV with Android ([Set up OpenCv with Android](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html)) and going from there. Since then I have set up OpenCV and have all the samples ([OpenCV android samples](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidSamples)) and tutorials which come with it working.

My problem is that I can't find a solid direction to go in from here, I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284214/simple-ocr-programming-tutorials-articles) whose answer points to a [tutorial](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/) however I am unsure if it will work with Android.

I am basically stuck trying to pick between continuing with OpenCV or trying other tools I have been reading about like tesseract or pure java [implementations](http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr).

Any advice about what direction to choose would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
Celic.

**TL;DR** **Need Advice about best Optical Character Recognition Implementation in Android**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look at JavaCV which a java interface to OpenCV

You can check something like Tesseract Android Tools (very decent): http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/

Here is a heads up for a problem we all run into at the beginning when using it: [Bytes Per Pixel value for byte representation of image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852300/bytes-per-pixel-value-for-byte-representation-of-image-in-android) (if you are using the camera ofc)

Comment: I will do mate thanks very much for the suggestions.. I have been playing around a bit with google goggles and am very impressed with its capabilities, is it built Tesseract do you know ??

Comment: I think so (this comes from memory and I can't seem to confirm it elsewhere)

Comment: Just letting you know I changed to Tesseract and got a sample OCR program running, thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

There's a tutorial [here](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) that's based on a fork of Tesseract Tools for Android. To get good results, you'll probably need to preprocess your images using some kind of thresholding.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I managed to get everything in that tutorial set up but when I ran the authors sample app, everything works fine until after I take the picture and accept it to carry out OCR on it at which point the app crashs.. I can't figure the errors out, if anybody has an idea of a solution it would be really helpful. http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/4351/screenshotat20120224094.png

Comment: Be sure to use ARGB_8888 format for the bitmap. Example [here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/source/browse/tesseract-android-tools-test/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/test/TessBaseAPITest.java).

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, that was the problem alright, had to put a 'bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);' outside an 'if (rotate != 0)' statement.